# avoid css hack for IE8 checkbox

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS3 to style a checkbox like this **[site](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles)** (Slide THREE)

html:

```
<div class="slideThree">
        <input type="checkbox" id="slideThree" name="check" /> 
        <label for="slideThree"></label>
</div>
```

css:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* SLIDE THREE */
.slideThree {
    width: 91px;
    height: 26px;
    background: #2B3D61;
    margin: 5px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.slideThree:after {
    content: 'OFF';
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
}

.slideThree:before {
    content: 'ON';
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.slideThree label {
    display: block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 24px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.slideThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    left: 44px;
}
```

IE8 doesn't support something here. **EDIT** I've have a `DOCTYPE` and I've removed `z-index` but that changed nothing. Checkbox still doesn't work. Is there a way to get around this or do I need to use conditional css in my html? If it degrades to just a simple checkbox would be fine for IE8.

Comment: :before and :after are supported in IE8 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304078(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Zenith is RIGHT, ie8 support :before and :after. -->
8 : Partial Support : z-index not respected, must use a doctype, must declare a :hover state if you use :hover:after/:hover:before

Comment: @MilchePatern anything else? I removed `z-index` and `doctype` exists and I don't use `:hover`. Still no change.

Comment: Well, find a demo that works on IE8 then copy-paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the dirty (and I mean Vegas dirty) IE conditional to overwrite the css to get it back down to just a checkbox.

aka

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="default-ie.css" type="text/css" /> <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to get around this is to create an additional classname for the `:after` and `:before` declarations and use JavaScript to add/remove these classes based on events.

Answer (score 0):

Add a span before the label and after the label:

```
<label for="slideThree"></label><span class="on">On</span><span class="off">Off</span>
```

CSS for .on:

```
font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
z-index: 0;
font-weight: bold;
```

CSS for .off:

```
font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
z-index: 0;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
```

Comment: Works for me: http://cssdeck.com/labs/alk8bfqu moved the span on to the end though.